# When cleanig tokenized data, how to use .isalpha() in a list of lists to return values, not Booleans?

Tags: nltk, list-comprehension

I'm practicing NLP with the nltk Library and I want to build myself an dataset for that. I combine several documents into a list of lists and then preprocess them. First I tokenize it, lowercase it and then I want to remove punctuation. It works for a vecor, but not for a list of lists:

Example for a vector:

```
a = 'This is a Testsentence and it is beautiful times 10!**!.' 
b = word_tokenize(a) 
c = [x.lower() for x in b] 
['this', 'is', 'a', 'testsentence', 'and', 'it', 'is', 'beautiful', 'times', '10', '.'] 
d = [x for x in c if x.isalpha()] 
['this', 'is', 'a', 'testsentence', 'and', 'it', 'is', 'beautiful', 'times']
```

Now I want to do it in a list of lists, but I fail to write the list comprehension at the end:

```
aa = 'This is a Testsentence and it is beautiful times 10.'
bb = 'It is a beautiful Testsentence?'
cc = 'Testsentence beautiful!'
dd = [aa, bb, cc]
ee = [word_tokenize(x) for x in dd]
ff = [[x.lower() for x in y] for y in ee]
[['this', 'is', 'a', 'testsentence', 'and', 'it', 'is', 'beautiful', 'times', '10', '.'], ['it', 'is', 'a', 'beautiful', 'testsentence', '?'], ['testsentence', 'beautiful', '!']]
```

This is where my problems start since I cant figure out how to write the list comprehension correctly.

```
gg = [[j.isalpha() for j in i] for i in ff]
```

This is the Result

```
[[True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False, False], [True, True, True, True, True, False], [True, True, False]]
```

But I want something like this:

```
[['this', 'is', 'a', 'testsentence', 'and', 'it', 'is', 'beautiful', 'times', '10', '.'], ['it', 'is', 'a', 'beautiful', 'testsentence', '?'], ['testsentence', 'beautiful', '!']]
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Your expected result is equal to `ff`. Can you update your question to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
gg = [[j for j in i if j.isalpha()] for i in ff]
```

This returns the expected answer

```
[['this', 'is', 'a', 'testsentence', 'and', 'it', 'is', 'beautiful', 'times'],
['it', 'is', 'a', 'beautiful', 'testsentence'],
['testsentence', 'beautiful']]
```